# How can I echo variable ordered by something

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-order-by

I created a table that contains `message, sender, to, time` I want to echo message ordered by time
that is my code.

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `table` GROUP BY `sender` ORDER BY `time` DESC")or die(mysql_error());
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$msg = $arr ['message'];
echo '</br>';
echo $msg;
}
```

that shows me the first message from each sender
I want to show the last message from each sender, So how can I do this

Thanks  :) 
Klaus

Comment: It shows not first but "*some*" message from each sender. It's not guaranteed to be the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM  (select * from table order by `time` desc) t1 GROUP BY `sender`
```

Comment: that shows me this error `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: sorry missing alias.. i did some edit.. try again

Comment: Thanks!! But the Order not working why?
sorry if I disturbed you.

Comment: it also order, but from alias table. i believe if you group by it will show first data they found from the table. I didn't know exact reason, sorry..